# How to get text in right side?

Tags: html, css, image

how to make that text would show in right side next to img.
code with css: https://codepen.io/FilipoV/pen/zYNMpjv

```
<img src="<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="twarz szefa kuchni" class="face-left">
        </figure>
        <section id="text-two">
            Młody Francuz to osoba fajna elo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eius ullam totam cum delectus quas saepe temporibus nostrum quibusdam molestiae iure esse vero expedita a.
        </section>" alt="twarz szefa kuchni" class="face-left">
        </figure>
        <section id="text-two">
            Młody Francuz to osoba fajna elo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eius ullam totam cum delectus quas saepe temporibus nostrum quibusdam molestiae iure esse vero expedita a.
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the image and the text in the same container. I did that and added a class named "box" as so:

```
body {
  background-color: #696969;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #45b345;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6vh;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 56px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #255325;
}

#header-one {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#header-two {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#header-one,
#header-two {
  text-align: center;
}

#header-three {
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #000;
}

.face-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex;
  border: 4px solid #45b345;
  border-radius: 250px;
}

#text-two {
  justify-content: right;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  display: flex
}

  <main>
    <article>
      <h1 id="header-one">
        Kuchnia Młodego Francuza
      </h1>
      <section>
        <h2 id="header-two">Młody Francuz </h2>
      </section>
      <header>
        <h3 id="header-three">Szef Kuchni</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="twarz szefa kuchni" class="face-left">

        <div id="text-two">
          Młody Francuz to osoba fajna elo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eius ullam totam cum delectus quas saepe temporibus nostrum
          quibusdam molestiae iure esse vero expedita a.
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

following your coding approach, I suggest you wrap

```
            <figure>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="twarz szefa kuchni" class="face-left">
            </figure>
```

in a single `div` with `class="some-class"` , that is;

```
  <div class="some-class">
         <header><h3 id="header-three">Szef Kuchni</h3></header>
         <figure>
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="twarz szefa kuchni" class="face-left">
        </figure>
  </div>
```

and style is as follows:

```
.some-class {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.some-class .face-left {
  margin-right: 15px // for example
}
```

And I think that does the Job. Hope it's helpful.